# Erro no comando "Git push: fatal: could not read Username"

Tags: github

Depois de commitar um arquivo e dar o comando "Git push origin master", um erro acontece dando a mensagem:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
```

Como resolver ?

Answer (score 3):

Tercio,
Seu repositório foi configurado errado. Para confirmar, digite:

```
git remote show origin -n
```

Verifique se o Fetch URL e Push  URL estão apontando para o seu repositório, caso não estejam:

Remova o atual

```
git remote rm origin
```

E inclua novamente

Para SSH

```
git remote add origin 'git@github.com:seu_usuario/seu_repositorio.git'
```

ou se estiver usando HTTPS

```
git remote add origin 'https://seu_usuario@github.com/usuario_dono_repositorio/nomerepositorio.git'
```

Comment: Verifiquei e está com as informações corretas. O erro persiste...

Comment: Uma dúvida: em 'git@github.com:seu_usuario/seu_repositorio.git' o 'seu_usuario' tem que ser obrigatoriamente o meu ?
Posso mandar para uma URL diferente ?

Comment: 1-Tem que obrigatoriamente ser o seu. 2 - Pode ser qualquer outro repositório.

Comment: Tentei de tudo e nada deu certo! Deve ser bug do windows!

Answer (score 3):

Eu sigo os seguintes comandos ao commitar:

```
git status
git add . ou git add -A
git commit -m "mensagem"
git pull origin master /*deve-se criar o remote 'origin' antes*/
git push origin
```

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma resposta para essa questão no stackoverflow inglês.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871549/error-when-push-commits-with-github-fatal-could-not-read-username

Na resposta e sugerida a execução dos comandos:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'
```

De qualquer maneira, também é sugerido a remoção do "https", e a utilização apenas do dominio "github.com".

Comment: Ja tentei também! Vou reinstalar! Deve ser bug do windows!

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do seu projeto deve existir uma pasta chamada ".git". Entre nessa pasta, e verifique se o arquivo "config" está com o endereço correto.

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://git@github.org:usuario/projeto.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/***texto em negrito**
```

Se não estiver correto, mude a url pelo arquivo. Caso isso não funcione, dê um git status e cole aqui para podermos olhar melhor.

Comment: está correto! Ja tentei de tudo! Vou reinstalar para ver!
Detalhe, é o GIT BASH do windows!

Answer (score -2):

pra quem tiver com problema no git, pra dar push, tá ai minha trajetória:

sou iniciante mas espero que isso te ajude!

primeiro eu vi tentei mudar as config:

```
Configurar username
git config --global user.name "seuUser"

Configurar username
git config --global user.email "seuEmail"
```

dai procurando achei esse video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISeXMoEcG8Q&ab_channel=MaximOrlov

```
ssh -v git@github.com

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C seuEmail@gmail.com

ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

ssh -vT git@github.com

ssh -T git@github.com:seuUsuario/seuRepositorio.git
```

Dai eu vi o video desse cara aki: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnuaVfi5MFU&ab_channel=CannedLaughter

```
gerenciar suas credenciais > credenciais windows > exclui a do git.
```

Dai fui tentar consertar oq o kra fez achei esse site: https://www.ti-enxame.com/pt/git/o-git-push-trava-ao-empurrar-para-o-github/1073588925/

```
git config --global core.askpass "git-gui--askpass"
```

nas resposta o @Drew falou "Mas então descobri que houve um erro com meu agente SSH. Então eu reiniciei o ssh-agent e… LUCRO"
tentei ver o erro e pesquisando achei isso: openssh username for 'https //github.com'
pra arrumar isso eu tive que reiniciar sshAgent:

```
executar do windows(Ctrl + r) > services.msc > OpenSSH Authentication (2click) > tipo de inicialização (deixar em automatico) > iniciar > ok
```

no fim acabei encontrando isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909221/why-is-github-asking-for-username-password-when-following-the-instructions-on-sc

trocar url https para ssh

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:ThiagodePaulaSouza/APS_4-semestre.git
```

e finalmente o push

```
git push origin main
```

É isso não tenho certeza se todos os passos são necessarios ou se há alguma coisa errado, mas foi oq deu certo...

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-ask).